# I want to open the link from rss list view inside the app (like opening with webview)

Tags: android-studio

I'm building an android app which list view the rss feed but when the feeds are clicked it open in a browser, but I want to open inside the app. I request help in solving the issue

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
            if(!isLongClick)
            {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);

            }
        }
    });
```

I expect the link should open inside the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebView` to open link in android app.

use the following code in your **activity**

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  
webview.loadUrl("INSERT_URL_HERE");
```

and following to the **.xml** file

```
 <WebView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:id="@+id/webView"  />
```

Comment: study -[this](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview) for further reference.